# Error message "Please enter valid date"

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment-gateway, validation, form-validation

**I am getting an error message when I use any date field for products or coupons. It tells me to enter a valid date. The dates are valid and there is no range that satisfies the system.**

Some payment cards are being rejected saying invalid dates also. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: Could you show us the error message specifically? It'd make it easier to debug and figure out what's going on

Comment: What is the language of your store ? I know there is an issue with date format which is different from English date format. For example for France, the format `dd/mm/aaaa` will throw the same error you have.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this problem is related to the language of your store.

You can check this issue for more details 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10580